# Setting locale based on preferences with fallbacks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, i18n

Consider the following code. Are the multiple assignments to the `loc` variable a code smell? If so, how can I refactor this?

```
def set_locale
  begin
    loc = user_signed_in? ? user_locale : browser_locale
    loc = browser_locale if loc.nil?
    loc = param_locale if loc.nil?
    loc = I18n.available_locales.include?(loc.to_sym) ? loc.to_sym : I18n.default_locale
  rescue
    loc = I18n.default_locale
  ensure
    cookies.permanent[:my_locale] = loc
  end
  I18n.locale = loc
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's a code smell. Mostly because `loc` seems to change type. It's one thing for it to be `nil` or a symbol; in that case it might "only" change value. But the last `to_sym` would seem to suggest it could also be a string or something.

In terms of code style, you could just use the `||=` assignment operator instead of `x = y if x.nil?`. That's the Ruby way to provide a fallback/default value in case of `nil`.

However, you're looking to prioritize locale selection, in which case I'd do something like:

```
locale = [user_locale, browser_locale, param_locale]
  .compact
  .map(&:to_sym)
  .detect { |locale| I18n.available_locales.include?(locale) }

I18n.locale = locale || I18n.default_local
cookies.permanent[:my_locale] = I18n.locale
```

It'll go through the list and return the first locale that's not `nil` and is available. If nothing's returned, it uses the default locale.

Note that I'm making an assumption here, namely that `user_locale` will return `nil` if the user isn't signed in. But you could also simply `unshift` the `user_locale` onto the array if the user is signed in, before doing the `detect`.

On another note: `param_locale` should, I think, be the first choice in all cases. If I go to a URL that has an explicit locale code in it, I'd expect to see *exactly* that page, in that language. URLs should be a permanent as you can make them. Sure, give me an option to view the same URL with a different locale, but don't second guess the URL itself.

Comment: Perfect. That looks awesome! I was thinking the array.compact thing as well but the its the detect part I unable to think of. As to param_locale, I totally agree with you that it should be the first option. How can I give you +1*100? ;)

Comment: Would you please mind explaining the `shift` the `user_locale` part?

Comment: @Saim I actually meant to write `unshift` - not `shift`. I just meant that you could build the basic array (i.e. browser & param locales), and only add the user's locale (via `unshift`, if it has to go first) if the user is indeed logged in, and _then_ do the compact/detect. It's just if you do need to check whether the user's logged in before you called `user_locale`. But if `user_locale` just returns nil for non-logged-in users, then you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Got it, thanks again. In this case, I think, returning `nil` from `user_locale` would make more sense and keeps it simple. Agree?

Comment: @Saim Yeah, I'd say so. Getting `nil` when asking for the user's locale without a user seems reasonable. The alternative would be raising an exception or something, which just seems like it'd complicate everything. Rather just have the method return a locale or nil. You have other ways to check if there is a logged-in user anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes on your code:

- Catch-all `rescue`s look suspicious. At least, you should only catch exceptions that inherit from `StandardError`. For that, you write `rescue => exc`. Anyway, what are you catching exactly here?
- `loc` has many different values, not good practice. Different values, different names.
- To save 3 characters you end up with a ambiguous variable name (loc*ale*? loc*ation*?). It's not worth it IMO.
- Use `||`.

I'd write:

```
def set_locale
  locale = (user_locale || browser_locale || param_locale).to_sym
  I18n.locale = locale.in?(I18n.available_locales) ? locale : I18n.default_locale
  cookies.permanent[:my_locale] = I18n.locale
end
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on Catch-all thing. Your `set_locale` version looks slick. Thanks I've learned a lot in even one code review. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

@Flambinos answer is great and covers many important things, but I really think this task should be split in 2-3 methods (depending if you could use list of this locale symbols anywhere else):

```
def symbolic_locales
  [user_locale, browser_locale, param_locale].compact.map(&:to_sym)
end

def proper_locale
  (symbolic_locales & I18n.available_locales).first || I18n.default_locale
end

def set_locale_to_proper
  cookies.permanent[:my_locale] = I18n.locale = proper_locale
end
```

This would allow to <s>play with</s>  refactor code easier.

Also, shorter methods tend to read better, because amount of natural documentation is higher.